# Null pointer comparison in C

Tags: c, pointers, null, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I don't why I don't enter this `if statement` while `(temp->next)->next` is 0. I also tried with casting `(temp->next)->next` to `(void*)` but it didn't work!

```
    void Mem_Coalesce(){


    list_t* temp;
    temp = freep;
    if( free_node_count == 2){

        if( ((char*)temp + (temp->size) )  == (char*)(temp->next)){
                printf("Entered if loop\n");
                        temp->size += (temp->next)->size;
                temp->next = NULL;
                free_node_count--;
        }



    }
    else {
         printf("\n coalescing the case that free list has 3+ nodes\n");
        while(temp->next != NULL  ){

            if( ((char*)temp + (temp->size)) == (char*)(temp->next)){

                    if( (temp->next)->next == NULL){

                        temp->size += (temp->next)->size;
                        temp->next = NULL; //seg fault happens here 
                                                break;


                    }else{

                    temp->size += (temp->next)->size;
                                        temp->next = (temp->next)->next;
                    ((temp->next)->next)->prev = temp;
                    }
                    free_node_count--;

            }
            temp=temp->next;

        }

    }



}
```

Here's the output I receive which has a seg fault:

```
Addr of temp->next is  7f4a836ae2e8

Addr of temp->next->next is  0

./cmd.sh: line 5: 31230 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) myprogram
```

Have I compared the pointer value against NULL incorrectly?

Comment: What is line 5? Is it the if statement?

Comment: it is just running the program in line 5 `#!/bin/bash
gcc -c -fpic mem.c -Wall -Werror
gcc -shared -o libmem.so mem.o
gcc -lmem -L. -o myprogram mymain.c -Wall -Werror
myprogram
`

Comment: @MonaJalal: if that is the output, those lines look fine; are you sure that the crash happens here? Have you tried to do some debugging (e.g. just adding some `printf` around to see up to where the program runs without crashing)? Could you show some more context?

Comment: @KristerAndersson line 5 of cmd.sh is `myprogram`

Comment: @KristerAndersson: that message is unrelated to the C code, it's just telling that the crash happens in the program started from line 5 of the `cmd.sh` shell script.

Comment: Add `-g` to the compilation flags, then use `gdb`. In `gdb` use `run`, then `backtrace`. It should tell you which line the crash happened. That should help us figure out what's wrong with the program.

Comment: I would expect that the first line after your 'if' block (line 5) tries to do something using (temp->next)->next, probably dereference it. It is null, so this will cause a seg fault.

Comment: @Baldrick you were right. The condition works but this line inside the condition doesn't work: `temp->next = NULL;`  I need to set `temp->next` to `NULL` but don't know how else I can do it. Any hint?

Comment: @MonaJalal Are you sure it's that line? Because that should be valid. Are you by any chance accessing `temp->next` **after** setting it to NULL?

Comment: please paste the entire code in the question. what you've shown has nothing wrong.

Comment: @Mona Jalal Yes, we really need to see what's in your 'if' block. That's where the problem almost certainly will be.

Comment: @Raja I think the problem raises from `break` . There was no `break` after `temp->next=NULL`. Now it is fixed.

Comment: alright, please mark this as resolved so that its off the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem raises from not having `break` . There was no `break` after `temp->next=NULL`. Now it is fixed.